# Creating an array out of decoded Firebase data

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the pod CodableFirebase to decode Firebase data and am attempting to place that data into an array. The problem I'm having is its placing each instance of data into a separate array causing me issues when I go to IndexPath it for use in a CollectionView.

The Code:

```
struct WatchList: Codable {
    let filmid: Int?
}

var watchList = [WatchList]()

        ref.child("users").child(uid!).child("watchlist").observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: { (info) in

            guard let value = info.value else { return }
            do {

                let list = try! FirebaseDecoder().decode(WatchList.self, from: value)
                self.watchList = [list]
                    print(self.watchList)

                    self.watchlistCollection.reloadData()
            }

    }, withCancel: nil)
```

Here is how the array is printed to the console:

```
[Film_Bee.ProfileView.WatchList(filmid: Optional(332562))]
[Film_Bee.ProfileView.WatchList(filmid: Optional(369972))]
[Film_Bee.ProfileView.WatchList(filmid: Optional(335983))]
```

When I use the array within the CollectionView it only counts and indexpaths the last array.

How can I place the data into a single array?

Comment: You might want to *add* the item to the array: `self.watchList.append(list)`

Comment: Ok, so this works in terms of placing the items in an array. The issue is though that it creates one array after another placing one item at time into the array. This means that if I have 100's of items to place that it would create 100's of arrays before completing. This might cause problems, is there a reason why it only adds one item at a time?

Comment: It prints like this: [item 1] [item 1, item 2] [item 1, item 2, item 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @vadian replacing

```
self.watchList = [list]
```

with

```
self.watchList.append(list)
```

Solved the question.